# Why does lazy loaded child object not get deleted for detached parent object

Tags: jpa

I have a doubt about how JPA handles lazy initialization of child objects.If i have object A containing a one-to-many with object B ( where B is lazy initialized) and i load object A( without accessing Set(B)) so that the Set(B) is null. Now if i detach A and then later merge(A), then why does JPA (in my case implemented by Hibernate) not delete the records for Set(B), given that Set(B) is now null? I have cascade=ALL set on Set(B).

I apologies if this is a trivial question or my understanding of the topic is not clear.

Comment: So you're question is: how the JPA knows that you explicitly set your one-to-many relationship to null or it isn't a null just because it wasn't initialized (because of lazy initialization)?

Answer (score 0):

`cascade=ALL` isn't enough. You also need to [delete orphans](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades).